# What is the proper way to POST data using javascript fetch?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I am trying to get away from jQuery and start using promises and arrow functions.  Try as I might, I can't seem to pass data to PHP using javascript fetch.

```
$btnarrmem.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        let $url = "getMember.php";
        let $data = {vid: '527571'}
        $data = JSON.stringify($data);
        console.log ($data);
        fetch ($url, {
            method:'POST',
            headers :{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            },
            body:$data
        })

        .then((response)=>{
            console.log (response.text())


        })
```

The result is always

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: *"Notice</b>:  Undefined index: data in /mnt/development/websites/arrows/getMember.php< on line <b>7<*emphasized text**
```

Which means to me that PHP is not getting data.

Here is the same function written using jQuery and it works just as I want it to

```
let $data = {vid: '527571'}
$data = JSON.stringify($data);
console.log($data);
$('button.qrymem').click(function () {
    let $data = {vid: '527571'}
    $data = JSON.stringify($data);
    console.log ($data);
    $.post('getMember.php', {data: $data}, function ($result) {
        console.log($result);
        $divquery.text($result);
    })

})
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions to get me moving in the proper direction.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery URL-encodes the data. You need to call `encodeURIComponent()` to do that, and then pass it as the value of the `data` parameter. The equivalent with `fetch()` is:

```js
$btnarrmem.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let $url = "getMember.php";
  let $data = {
    vid: '527571'
  };
  $data = JSON.stringify($data);
  console.log($data);
  fetch($url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      body: `data=${encodeURIComponent($data)}`
    })

    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.text())


    })
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me.  I get the same error "undefined index data..."

What does work is changing the php code to $data = file_get_contents('php://input';  But this then breaks jQuery.

Comment: Need to fix the `Content-type` header.